# Mail Dispatcher Agent: Could not access the outbox folder (Unknow error. (Failed to fetch the resource collection.))

Tags: ubuntu, kde, email, kubuntu

Why am I receiving this error message on Kubuntu since I upgraded to 12.04 and how can I make it stop appearing? It appears as a pop up balloon above the system tray.

`Mail Dispatcher Agent: Could not access the outbox folder (Unknow error. (Failed to fetch the resource collection.)).`

Comment: [Maybe this helps](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97385)  (Scrolling down leads to more sensitive methods than deleting the configuration)

Comment: Implemented the method written at Thu Oct 27, 2011 12:58 pm as it describes my issue exactly. Can't reboot right now, but I'll let you know in a few days once I did.

Comment: @sr_: I definitely think you should add your comment as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This forum thread](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97385) discusses the issue and includes various solutions/workarounds, such as [deleting `/.config/akonadi`](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97385#p205978),

> Rather than removing the akonadi configuration, I edited `~/.config/akonadi/aknoadiserverrc` and changed `StartServer=true` to `StartServer=false`, and then rebooted (although logging out and back in should have been sufficient). [<sup>(1)</sup>](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97385#p205987)

or this one

> Hi,
>   I had the same problem here, also on a Kubuntu system that has undergone many distribution upgrades.
>
> I found the following solution without having to delete Akonadi's configuration or disabling it completely:
>   **In the "Akonadi configuration" dialog (where you configure the Akonadi ressources), I had an e-mail ressource named "Local Folder". Deleting it made the startup warning go away.** [<sup>(2)</sup>](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97385#p206223)

Comment: I removed the e-mail ressource named "Local Folder" from "Akonadi configuration". Works like a charm. Thnx!

Comment: **"Akonadi configuration"** dialog and remove **"Local Folder"** (maybe other not connected resources) should be the _preferred_ way.